# Options panel global variable?

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a WordPress options panel based on 
http://en.bainternet.info/2012/my-options-panel

In the article it states to call the stored options to use

```
//get the data to an array
$data = get_option('demo_options');
//access each field by its id
echo $data['text_field_id'];
```

Which works, the only problem I have is that if I want to call some information for say the header.php and the footer.php or any other page I have to include the line

```
$data = get_option('demo_options');
```

at the top of every page otherwise I can not call the data, which seems repetitive.

I have tried to create a global variable in the functions.php file like;

```
global $data
$data = get_option('demo_options');
```

but that doesn't work.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this so I don't need to add the line to the top of every page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In `functions.php`:

```
$data = get_option('demo_options');
```

In any other theme template file (`header.php`, `single.php`, `page.php`):

```
global $data; 
var_dump( $data );
```

To have a variable defined in `header.php` and not having to use `global $var` in other template files, the following has to be done:

- define the variable in `header.php`
- instead of `get_header();` in other theme template files, use `include 'header.php';`
- this way, you can reference the variable directly without having to declare the `global`

Comment: But this just creates the same problem i.e. having to add the global $data line to every page.

Comment: Well, you said you tried this and it didn't work. This way works. I don't think you can avoid calling the `global $var`, or in substitution calling a custom function defined in `functions.php` (but it would be basically the same as `get_option()`). These options values are cached, so there's no penalty in calling it multiple times. I'll add a non-standard solution to the Answer.